# How to upload a user profile image

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, url, photo

I am trying to upload a profile image to the user profile but the profile image doesn't appear on the profile page there are no errors popping up so how do I restructure this code to fix this issue?

```
 if let ProfileImageUrl = dictionary?["photo"] as? String {
                     let url = URL(string: ProfileImageUrl)
                    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { ( data, response, Error ) in
                        if Error != nil {
                            print(Error!)
                        return
            }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.ProfileImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        }
```

Comment: I am not seeing any Firebase code in the question and you don't appear to be using Firebase Storage to store the image (you should consider that). How does this relate to firebase and what specifically is the issue? Using URLSession? If so, you're missing a `dataTask?.resume()`. Check out [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3244963-urlsession-tutorial-getting-started) as it will really help.

Answer (score 1):

The "Error" in trailing closure should be "error". It's just a matter of naming convention, doesn't necessarily cause the code to fail.

Found the problem, you're missing ".resume()" on the data task. The following code works :

```
if let imageUrl = urlString{
        let url = URL(string: imageUrl)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print("Error : \(error)")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }.resume()

    }
```

Comment: an error popped up saying (Use of unresolved identifier 'error')

Comment: Hi Norman, I've updated the answer.

Comment: how do I get rid of the error (Use of unresolved identifier 'urlString') @https://stackoverflow.com/users/10237398/christopher-jude

Comment: Replace : `urlString` with your source of urlString. I believe it's `dictionary?["photo"] as? String`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You will need to uploaded by button (browser uploaded ) 
so just create button and then create button action

```
@IBAction func doUplodPImg(_ sender: Any) {
    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self

    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary

    image.allowsEditing = false

    self.present(image, animated: true)
    {
        //After it is complete
    }

}
```

and also add one function

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
{
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
            {
                profileImg.image = image
            }
            else
            {
                //Error message
            }
    guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }
    profileImg.image = selectedImage

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now you can successfully uploaded photo in UIimageview. please change your own name profileImg to your UIimageview name

make sure you added UIImagePickerControllerDelegate in your top viewcontroller delegate

and If you want to uploaded in server  then just use alamofire method

```
    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            if let _image = self.profileImg.image {
                if let imageData = _image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7) {
                    multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "profile_image", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                }
            }
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
    }, to: url, method: .post)
    { (response) in
        switch response {
        case .success(let upload,_,_):
            upload.responseJSON { res in
                let response = res.result.value as? NSDictionary
                print(response)
  }
        case .failure(_): break

        }

}
```

change your parameters name im using this profile_image (server side parameter)

Hope it will be helpful. let me know if you find any difficulty.